# How to access the instance variable?

Tags: python, sql, sql-server, database, odbc

I have used a 'class' named 'CMS'. Also,i have defined a method def ConnectDB(),Where i have loaded the driver and created a cursor object to execute a query.Whenever i try to access the cursor object,it's giving me an attribute error.

```
obj.cursor.execute(sql,v)
AttributeError: CMS instance has no attribute 'cursor'
```

How do I resolve it?Refer the code below to understand the problem statement clearly.Thanks in advance.

```
class CMS:

 def ConnectDB(self):
  server = '192.121.063.012'
  database = 'fghr_db'
  username = 'abcdef'
  password = 'zzzzzzz'
  connStr = 'DRIVER=/opt/microsoft/msodbcsql17/lib64/libmsodbcsql-    17.2.so.0.1;SERVER='+server+';DATABASE='+database+';'+ 'UID='+username+';    PWD='+ password+';Port=1270'
  cnxn = pyodbc.connect(connStr)
  cursor = cnxn.cursor()

def ReadCsv(self,filepath):
  data = csv.reader(open(filepath))
  print data
  h=data.next()
  result=[]
  for x in data:
   c=list(x)
   result.append(c)
  return result

obj=CMS()
obj.ConnectDB()
sql="INSERT INTO StudentCsv  VALUES (?,?,?,?,?)"
z=obj.ReadCsv("Student.csv")
for v in z:
 print v
 obj.cursor.execute(sql,v)
obj.cnxn.commit()
```

ERROR getting like below:

> obj.cursor.execute(sql,v) AttributeError: CMS instance has no
>   attribute 'cursor'

Comment: Because you didn't define any of them as instance attributes. Passing `self` to the method is not enough; you need `self.cursor = cnxn.cursor()`, and the same for all all other values that you want to be instance attributes

Comment: yeah,I have tried it.But,it's giving me a global name error.                         NameError: global name 'server' is not defined

Comment: Sure, because if you change `server = '192.121.063.012'` to `self.server = '192.121.063.012'`, then you also need to reference it as `self.server` when you try to use it in the string concatenation; `17.2.so.0.1;SERVER='+self.server+...`